# How to use Email services

Tags: apex-email-service

I have created a email service to receive a emil from a provided email id I want to print the emiail body in debug log for this I write some debug to that but my problem is nothing get printes in debug log so will you please suggest me how to print email body in debug log.

My email service class code -

```
global class ProcessCaseEmail implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler
{
    ProcessCaseEmail ()
    {
        System.debug('=======');
    }

    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email,Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope)
    {

        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
        String myPlainText= '';
        myPlainText = email.plainTextBody;
        System.debug('Plain text+++++++++++' + myPlainText );
        List<String> parts = myPlainText.split('\n');

        List<String> columns;
        for(integer i=0;i<parts.size();i++)
        {

            System.debug('Parts+++++     ['+i+']   '+parts[i] );
            system.debug('Length of the parts ['+i+']  '+parts[i].length());

        }
        return result;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you turned on debug logging for the context user of the email service?

Comment: can you please elaborate more.

Comment: The answer below covers this.

Answer (score 2):

You are only printing the plain text body, perhaps you are sending your email as HTML?

this works perfectly for me:

```
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope)
    {
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

        System.debug('HTML BODY: '+email.htmlBody);
        System.debug('TEXT BODY: '+email.plainTextBody);
        System.debug('SUBJECT: '+email.subject);

        return result;
    }
```

Do make sure you put on debug logging for it to work, go to:

- Setup
- Administration Setup
- Montitoring
- Debug Logs
- Add a New
  monitored user (make sure you choose the user you setup for handling
  your inbound email)

Send your mail, refresh the page, there should now be logs available:

[image: Log Overview]
[image: Log]

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are the context user - you can just monitor the logs in the Developer Console as they occur.